# Maximum text size in diagram exceeded- mermaid.js

Tags: javascript, mermaid

I am using mermaid 8.8.1 and trying to render a large diagram and getting an error "Maximum text size in diagram exceeded". Another answer here [Maximum Text Size In Diagram Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870481/maximum-text-size-in-diagram-exceeded) recommends overriding "maxTextSize" setting, but I dont find this in the mermaidAPI configuration settings https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/blob/develop/docs/Setup.md#mermaidapi-configuration-defaults.
Where can I find this setting or is there another work around to fix this error?

Comment: The workaround worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

which in [defaultConfig.js](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/blob/74b1219d62dd76d98d60abeeb36d4520f64faceb/src/defaultConfig.js#L39)

```js
const config = {
  theme: 'default',
  themeVariables: theme['default'].getThemeVariables(),
  themeCSS: undefined,
  /* **maxTextSize** - The maximum allowed size of the users text diagram */
  maxTextSize: 50000,
  // ...
}
```